# Where are Azure WebJob's BlobInput and BlobOutput classes?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I am creating a Azure WebJob console application that resizes images uploaded to blob storage. When following any of the code samples online I am unable to reference and use the BlobInput and BlobOutput input parameter attributes. I am using the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Jobs 0.3.0-beta (and Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Core).

Which namespaces are BlogInput and BlobOutput found in? Is there another NuGet package that I need?

Here is my code which does not compile because it cannot resolve BlobInput and BlobOutput:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Jobs;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobHost host = new JobHost();
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }

        public static void SquishNewlyUploadedPNGs([BlobInput("input/{name}")] Stream input, [BlobOutput("output/{name}")] Stream output)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are attributes, so the type names should be BlobInputAttribute, BlobOutputAttribute.  Should be in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.dll in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs namespace.  Or at least they were there at one time.  Try opening all the Jobs sdk dlls in, say, JustDecompile and searching for them.

Comment: When I decompile Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.dll those attributes are no where to be found. This is the assembly from the latest version of the NuGet package 0.3.0-beta. If I use an older package, say 0.2.0-alpha, the assembly is called Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.dll and they are there as expected. So the upgrade from 0.2.0 to 0.3.0 not only rebrands the assembly name from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs to Microsoft.Azure.Jobs but also loses BlogInputAttribute and BlobOutputAttribute. I suppose one option would be to use 0.2.2 but I'd rather learn to use WebJobs using the current version

Comment: Interestingly enough I see that Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.dll contains BlobAttribute and BlobTriggerAttribute. The latter is described in the assembly as "Represents an attribute that binds a parameter to an Azure Blob, causing the method to run when a blob is uploaded". I'm guessing this is a descendant of BlobInputAttribute, perhaps MS is still playing around with names.

Comment: Could be.  I don't have the SDK, so I can't say for sure :/

Comment: Attribute names changed, see my answer below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Beta version of Azure WebJobs SDK we changed the attribute names as described below. The functionality remained the same.

```
BlobInputAttribute   -> BlobTriggerAttribute
BlobOutputAttribute  -> BlobAttribute
QueueInputAttribute  -> QueueTriggerAttribute
QueueOutputAttribute -> QueueAttribute
```

Also, the package names changed. You should use:

```
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Jobs/0.3.0-beta
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Core/0.3.0-beta
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, the updated names are working for me exactly as expected, thank you for the fast response.