# Jobs from an earlier version of the Azure WebJobs SDK have been detected

Tags: azure, web, sdk, jobs, azure-webjobs

I'm using web-jobs SDK pre-release version and from few minutes ago Im getting this warning message:

Jobs from an earlier version of the Azure WebJobs SDK have been detected. Please upgrade the jobs to the latest version in order to see their status in the dashboard. Please visit this article for more information about the Azure WebJobs SDK.

I would be thankful if you help me with this.

Comment: The article link directs to: http://www.asp.net/#migratewebjobs which actually has no article. Is this a warning being put in place for an upcoming release??

Answer (score 1):

Later edit: the link should work now

---

The page for that link is not yet live. It will be published soon, sorry for the inconvenience.

Meanwhile, to upgrade, get the latest WebJobs SDK packages (notice the package names changed so you might want to remove the old ones):

```
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Jobs/0.3.0-beta
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Core/0.3.0-beta
```

Also notice that some attribute names changed: 
[Where are Azure WebJob's BlobInput and BlobOutput classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286214/where-are-azure-webjobs-blobinput-and-bloboutput-classes)